# charles issue with ios simulator and googleapi.com

Tags: ssl, google-api, ios-simulator, charles-proxy

I am getting an encrypted response from googleapis when I try to view the request in Charles, but I have the ios simulator ssl cert verified. Other request are plain text. Does anyone know why this doesn't work in Charles? Is there another tool to examine the request my app sends to googleapis.com?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the request/response you are trying to monitor and click 'Enable SSL Proxying' to put that url into the enabled list. You can also do this manually by going to Proxy - SSL Proxy Settings.